# Can XMPP MIXes be end-to-end encrypted?

Tags: xmpp, omemo

Alternatively phrased, is XEP-0369 (Mediated Information eXchange) compatible with OMEMO in XMPP? If yes, are there any existing implementations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Alternatively phrased, is XEP-0369 (Mediated Information eXchange)
>   compatible with OMEMO in XMPP?

Yes, but I am not aware of any implementations.